# Random access pagination with search_after on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, nestjs, random-access

There are more than 10 thousand documents in my index, but I cannot access all documents with search. I may also have performance problems with the scroll API. I found a method on how to overcome this with search_after in this [article](https://dev.to/tariqabughofa/3-approaches-to-scroll-through-data-in-elasticsearch-4ii3#:%7E:text=Random%20access%20with%20search_after).

With this article, I can list all documents without using function score, but it seems that pagination cannot be done using a query. Is there a correct way to search and page through all content?

I want to see the documents by filtering them according to some conditions, but while there should be more than 10k results as a result of filtering and search API, there is max 10k documents. While navigating between pages, it is necessary to be able to move to the 7th page while on the 3rd page. At this point, search_after or scroll are not useful.

Comment: The technique explained in that article is valid for a **single query** and as long as the content of your index doesn't change... If those two constraints apply to you, then you can use that technique of having a pagination index and using it to randomly access your index data using search_after.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is more than one query, so I cannot solve this problem @Val

Comment: Maybe you should explain a bit more your use case and why you need to retrieve more than 10K docs. Your description of the problem is pretty shallow